# How should count and distinct be used together?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a database mydb, and a table dbo.mytable in it.

I want to see if three columns (Contract_Number, Payment_Number, Task_Number) of the table can form a candidate key, by https://stackoverflow.com/a/34468508/156458

```
 SELECT count (DISTINCT [Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number])
 FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

but the execution gives an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

I was wondering what is going wrong?

Without count, it works fine. How should count and distinct be used together?

I also tried:

```
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number]
  FROM [PAD_Dev].[dbo].[Line_Level_Custom])
```

but the execution gives an error:

```
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
  Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Outside of a aggregate function, `DISTINCT` effects the dataset; every single *row* must have a distinct set of values. Aggregate functions, like `COUNT`, expect a **scalar** expression to `COUNT`, which `[Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number]` is not. Perhaps you want something like `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT([Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number]))` or `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(',',[Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number]))`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34468508/156458 uses count directly outside distinct

Comment: Did you mean to add anything alongside that link, @Tim ?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support tuples of multiple columns there. Not sure if other RDBMS do or if that was just pseudo code

Comment: How is it done in sql server and in postgresql @martin

Comment: How I would do this in practice depends on what else I need to determine in the same query. If I just wanted the scalar value I would probably do `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT [Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number] FROM   [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]) X `

Comment: That isn't the code I posted. You are missing the required alias

Comment: @martin why is an alias not in use necessary?

Comment: `SELECT [Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number], COUNT(*) FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] GROUP BY [Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: You might find a scenario where the query is ambiguous without a alias. Mostly though it's just required syntax. Anonymous types is a newish trend in modern languages and SQL is quite old too...?

Comment: @shawn could you tell me what scenarios? What's anonymous type?

Comment: I was trying to imagine a scenario whether the syntax might be ambiguous and thus the rule became that it was required. I don't have an example and ultimately it's a minor irritation we've always had. As for "anonymous types" there are languages like C++, C#, and Java where you can make a new type on the fly (aka "a table" as a rough parallel) without giving it a name. This is all just my attempt at historical perspective though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you play with `Row_Number` ?

```
;with CTE as
(
SELECT row_number()over(partition  by [Contract_Number] order by [Contract_Number]) rownum
,[Contract_Number], [Payment_Number], [Task_Number])
 FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
 )
 select * from CTE where rownum=1
```

OR `Count function with partition`

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Contract_Number]) [Contract_Number],
[Payment_Number], [Task_Number]
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

*Query is not tested